# In △ABC, AB = 4 cm, BC = 6 cm, and AC = 8 cm. Let D be a point on AC so that BD = AB. Find AD.

Tags: geometry

In △ABC, AB = 4 cm, BC = 6 cm, and AC = 8 cm. Let D be a point on AC so that BD = AB. Find AD.

The correct answer was 11/2 cm and I tried to find out the reason why the answer was such.
I first tried looking for similar triangles but it didn't work. Then I also assumed that the height of the isosceles triangle is equal to the height of △ABC, but it was totally different from the correct answer. I would appreciate it if someone could help me find the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Another method is to drop a perpendicular line from B onto AC which meets AC at point E thus forming two right triangles ABE and CBE. These share a common side BE whereby AE is half the length of AD (the perpendicular line BE bisects the isosceles triangle ABD).
Using the Pythagorean theorem where x = AE:

$4^2 - x^2 = 6^2 -(8-x)^2$

$16 - x^2 = 36 - 64 +16x -x^2$

$16 = -28 + 16x$

$16x = 44$

$x = \frac{11}{4}$

Hence $AD = \frac{11}{2}$

Answer (score 2):

Let $\overline{AB} = c$, $\overline{AC} = b$, $\overline{BC} = a$, $\overline{AD}= x$ and $\overline{BD} = y (=c)$. Using the cosine rule repeatedly,

$$ \cos A = \frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc} = \frac{64+16-36}{2\times 8\times 4} = \frac{11}{16} \\ x^2 = y^2 + c^2 - 2 c y\cos B \\ \cos B = \cos\left(\pi - 2\arccos\left(\frac{11}{16}\right)\right) = \frac{7}{128} \\ x = \sqrt{16+16-2\times 4\times 4\times \frac{7}{128}} = \frac{11}{2}$$